# Integrate Tableau into Shiny project with Javascript API

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, tableau-api, shinyjs

I'm trying to put a Graph in a Shiny project I'm working on. I found that the most convenient way to do so is to use the Javascript API and the shinyjs package.

The Javascript API for Tableau is explained in detail [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/help.htm)
and my script looks like this. According to the instructions it is correct, and according to shinyjs the function name has to be preceded by "shinyjs."

```
   function  shinyjs.init() {
    var containerDiv document.getElementById("vizContainer"),
    url = "https://public.tableau.com/profile/daniel.cuartas#!/vizhome/Indicadores_25/Pregunta";
    var viz new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url); 
}
```

And the chunk of code included in my Shiny ui.R is this

```
               ui = fluidPage(
             includeScript("https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.js"),
             useShinyjs(),
             extendShinyjs(script = "C:/Users/Antonia/Downloads/SaberDigital/init.js"),
             tags$div(id = 'vizContainer'),
                      js$init()

           )
```

I get back the next error:

```
Error : shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript file: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.
```

What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: @HubertL you are absolutely right. I pasted the wrong js file. I have since updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues with your code:

1- You have to use `tags$head(tags$script())` which tells the browser to load the script instead of `includeScript` which include the JS code.

2- The shinyjs expanding function must be written like this `shinyjs.init = function()` and to simplify I inlined it rather than having it in a separate file

3- The URL format to you viz must have this format `https://public.tableau.com/views/YOUR-VISUALIZATION`

4- The `shinyjs.init` function must be called by the server function, not the ui

```
shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$script(src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.js")),
  extendShinyjs(text = "
shinyjs.init = function(){
var containerDiv = document.getElementById('vizContainer');
url = 'https://public.tableau.com/views/Indicadores_25/Pregunta';
var viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url); 
}"),
  tags$div(id = 'vizContainer')),
      server = function(input, output, session){js$init()})
```

Comment: This completely solves the problem, I don't get any error back but instead I get a blank space. Any insights on why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it works, now the problem seems to be a bug. I'll post another question. Thanks a lot.